# Enable root password verification while login with serial console in Yocto

Tags: linux, root, yocto, openembedded

I'm trying to enable login verification for root user.

With adding below lines into local.conf, I can see password requested while login as root with SSH.

```
IMAGE_FEATURES_remove = "debug-tweaks empty-root-password"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES_remove = "debug-tweaks empty-root-password"
```

However, if I tried to login as root with Serial Console (ttyS0), it just successfully logged in without any password verification or requests.

Does anyone know how to enable login verification for serial console's access?

P.S

I didn't set any default password for root, so that it should never allow login for root user.
And even if I set password for root, it still doesn't need password's input while login via serial console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And even if I set password for root, it still doesn't need password's input while login via serial console.

Are you sure it is set correctly? 
This is what I use to modify root user password (in a `.bb` file, or `.inc` file):

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS += "usermod -P mypassword root;"
```

If you don't want login at all, maybe you can change the shell of the user:

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS += "usermod -s /bin/nologin root;"
```

The user will exist, will be used by applciations, but will the login will not be possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
With `usermod -s /bin/nologin root` , I could successfully disable login of root user.
And after I added password for root (not use default), verification showed up.

Answer (score -1):

poky/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd-serialgetty/serial-getty@.service

- ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -8 --autologin root -L %I @BAUDRATE@ $TERM
- ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -8 -L %I @BAUDRATE@ $TERM

https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/FAQ:How_do_I_set_or_change_the_root_password

Comment: Maybe this needs some explanations ?

Comment: Thank you but this is for enabling autologin with serial console.
It can't solve no verification problem which I asked.
With "--autologin root" deleted in serial-getty@.serivce, "login user" will be asked after boot.
However, you can still login without any password's request after typed in "root".